# Difference between character and block files

Tags: c, linux, file, buffer, device

I'm studying about Drivers programming for Linux kernel. I found out that there are 2 types of of Device files, character file and block file.

For this moment, I don't really want to know what a device file is exactly about, but I would like to know if there is an abstract concept of **character (non-buffered)** and **block (buffered) files** in C language (I mean if it is a concept relative to the Operating System or to C language);

Comment: Please don't expect _sample code_ from StackOverflow. Specific answers for specific questions. I've edited your question to make it more focused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> to know if there is an abstract concept of character (non-buffered)
>   and block (buffered) files in C language (I mean if it is a concept
>   relative to the Operating System or to C language);

It's relative to the Operating System yes.

> to get some sample codes to show the difference between them in
>   language C (independently than if it's about a device file).

You will see no difference. I mean that there's no *special C features* for a character device or a block one. Of course the code will be different but only the logic, not the language.

[This tutorial](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/Module-HOWTO/) is pretty awesome if you need more informations.

Comment: Fast and focused! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In C there is no concept of a character file. You have streams, which you can read ony byte after the other, but that is independent of the underlying hardware. And the C library may or may not buffer it.

On the other hand, on the driver level, a character device is a device which can provide only ony value after the other (serial port would be such an example), as opposed to a block device, which can provide a defined buffer (like a hard disc, CD drive, etc.).

Comment: First, thank you already for this precious additional information. However, I don't really get what you mean by "only one value after the other", is it the same as the concept of sequential files in C language?

Comment: On a serial port, you can read one value after the other. You can't seek ahead, or rewind. However, on a disc, you can seek to the specified sector and read it. Additionaly, on the serial port you always have one byte to read. On a disc, you provide a whole memory block and the disc drive will fill it accordingly. Hence character device, versus. block device.